# Angular Material md-datepicker open in full screen with white background

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material

I´m working with md-datepicker. In some screen resolutions (or if I do a zoom out in the browser), the calendar open in Full Screen Size and all the background is White. Also, the bar that shows the days, is hidden.

I attach an Image for reference. How can i debug for find the reason of that behavior? I have been modifying some styles, and using diferent containers´ options, but without success. Thanks in advance for your help and ideas!

Image: https://s10.postimg.org/604p76qix/md_datepicker_full_Screen.png
https://postimg.org/image/hp8ov5hhh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in 1.1.0. Version 1.1.1 fixes it.

Workaround is setting `overflow:hidden;` on the `md-datepicker-input-mask` class

Comment: I have 1.1.1 and still suffer from this problem.